# SQLite syntax error code 1, tried to fix but fixes doesn't helped

Tags: java, sqlite, crash, syntax-error

Build is successful, but app crashes with error attached below when I try to open my database via `myDataBaseManager.openDataBase()`

There is an crash log:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main Process: com.example.smartwardrobe, PID: 9535                                                                                                 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
{com.example.smartwardrobe/com.example.smartwardrobe.LoginActivity}: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "myTableOfClothes": syntax 
error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: myTableOfClothes
```

And there is a class with construction of database:

```
   
    public final class MyDataBaseContract {
        public static final String USER_TABLE_NAME = "usersMyTable";
        public static final String USER_ID = "userID";
        public static final String USER_LOGIN = "login";
        public static final String USER_PASSWORD = "password";

        public static final String CLOTHE_TABLE_NAME = "clothesMyTable";
        public static final String CLOTHE_COLOUR = "clothe_Colour";
        public static final String CLOTHE_WARMTH = "clotheWarmth";
        public static final String CLOTHE_TYPE = "clotheType";
        public static final String CLOTHE_NAME = "clotheName";
        public static final String CLOTHE_IMAGE_INDEX = "clotheImageIndex";
        public static final String CLOTHE_OWNER_ID = "ownerId";
        public static final String CLOTHE_ID = "clotheID";

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wardrobeDatabase.db";
        public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

        public static final String USER_TABLE_STRUCTURE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                USER_TABLE_NAME + " (" + USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + USER_LOGIN + " TEXT," +
                USER_PASSWORD + " TEXT)";
        public static final String CLOTHE_TABLE_STRUCTURE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                CLOTHE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + CLOTHE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + CLOTHE_COLOUR + " TEXT," +
                CLOTHE_WARMTH + " TEXT," + CLOTHE_TYPE + " TEXT," + CLOTHE_NAME + " TEXT," +  CLOTHE_IMAGE_INDEX + " TEXT," +
                CLOTHE_OWNER_ID + " TEXT)";

        public static final String DROP_CLOTHE_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + CLOTHE_TABLE_NAME;
        public static final String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXIST " + USER_TABLE_NAME;
    }
```

There is a MyDataBaseManager class:

```
@SuppressLint("Range")
public class MyDataBaseManager {
    private Context context;
    private MyDataBaseHelper myDataBaseHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public MyDataBaseManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        myDataBaseHelper = new MyDataBaseHelper(context);
    }

    public void openDataBase(){
        database = myDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void closeDataBase(){
        myDataBaseHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertUserToUserDataBase(String login, String password){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MyDataBaseContract.USER_LOGIN, login);
        cv.put(MyDataBaseContract.USER_PASSWORD, password);
        database.insert(MyDataBaseContract.USER_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }

    public void insertClotheToClotheDatabase(String type, String warmth, String colour,
                                             String name, int ownerId){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_TYPE, type);
        cv.put(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_WARMTH, warmth);
        cv.put(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_COLOUR, colour);
        cv.put(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_NAME, name);
        cv.put(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_OWNER_ID, ownerId);
        database.insert(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
    }


    public ArrayList<Clothe> getAllClothesByOwnerId(int ownerId){
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_TABLE_NAME,
                null, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        ArrayList<Clothe> clothes = new ArrayList<>();

        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            if(ownerId == cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_OWNER_ID))){
                Clothe clothe = new Clothe(
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_ID)),//Clothe ID
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_WARMTH)), //Clothe warmth
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_TYPE)), // Clothe type
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_COLOUR)), //Clothe colour
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_NAME)), //Clothe name
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.CLOTHE_OWNER_ID))); //Owner ID
                clothes.add(clothe);
            }

        }
        cursor.close();
        return clothes;
    }

    public boolean doesLoginExist(String login){
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MyDataBaseContract.USER_TABLE_NAME,
                null, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            if(login.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_LOGIN))))
            {
                cursor.close();
                return true;
            };
        }
        cursor.close();
        return false;
    }

    public User getUserByLogin(String login){
        if (!doesLoginExist(login)) return null;
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MyDataBaseContract.USER_TABLE_NAME,
                null, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            if(login.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_LOGIN)))){
                User user = new User(login, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_PASSWORD)),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_ID)));
                cursor.close();
                return user;

            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }

    public User getUserByID(int userID){
        Cursor cursor = database.query(MyDataBaseContract.USER_TABLE_NAME,
                null, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            if (userID == cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_ID))){
                User user = new User(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_LOGIN)),
                        cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_PASSWORD)),
                        cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDataBaseContract.USER_ID)));
                cursor.close();
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also, there is a class with usage of `myDataBaseManager.openDataBase()`:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private MyDataBaseManager myDataBaseManager;
    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        //Buttons
        Button btn_login = findViewById(R.id.btn_LoginPage_SignIn);
        Button btn_register = findViewById(R.id.btn_LoginPage_OpenRegisterDialog);
        //Edit Texts
        EditText et_login = findViewById(R.id.et_LoginPage_Login);
        EditText et_password = findViewById(R.id.et_LoginPage_Password);
        //Other
        myDataBaseManager = new MyDataBaseManager(this);
        Activity activity = this;

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(v -> startRegistration(activity, myDataBaseManager));

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String login = et_login.getText().toString();
            if (myDataBaseManager.doesLoginExist(login)){
                User tempUser = myDataBaseManager.getUserByLogin(login);
                String password = et_password.getText().toString();
                if(tempUser.getPassword().equals(password)){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("UserID", tempUser.getUserID());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    myDataBaseManager.closeDataBase();
                    finishActivity(0);
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Password is incorrect. Check it and try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else Toast.makeText(activity, "User with this login does not exist. Sign up!(^_^)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       myDataBaseManager.openDataBase();
    }
```

I checked my code few times in searching the error in syntaxis of database or error in other classes, but hadn't find anything.

Additional information:
Virtual device: Pixel 6 pro API 33

Comment: You did not post the code that throws the error.

Comment: Yes. My bad. Attached it now with more explanation of crash.

Answer (score 0):

The specific error is that the syntax near "myTableOfClothes" is incorrect. It seems like you are trying to create a table with that name but it doesn't exist in the code you shared, it seems like the table name may be misspelled, or it's not the correct table name that you are trying to create.

Please check the name of the table you are trying to create, and also check if you are using the correct SQL statement for creating the table.
In the code you've shared, the table is called "clothesMyTable" in the MyDataBaseContract class and the statement to create it is called CLOTHE_TABLE_STRUCTURE.

Also, ensure that the table is not already created and you are trying to create it again, if so you should drop it first before creating it again with the DROP_CLOTHE_TABLE statement.

It's also important to note that, if you are using hardcoded string literals in your SQL statements, make sure that you are using the correct table and column names.

public static final String CLOTHE_TABLE_NAME = "clothesMyTable";

public static final String CLOTHE_TABLE_STRUCTURE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
CLOTHE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + CLOTHE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + CLOTHE_COLOUR + " TEXT," +
CLOTHE_WARMTH + " TEXT," + CLOTHE_TYPE + " TEXT," + CLOTHE_NAME + " TEXT," +  CLOTHE_IMAGE_INDEX + " TEXT," +
CLOTHE_OWNER_ID + " TEXT)";

Also, you need to update the table name everywhere it's used in the code to match the correct table name.

Additionally, make sure you are using the correct SQL

Comment: The structure of the database itself is correct. Also, in each place of the code I use a reference to a constant with the name of a specific table to avoid confusion. At the same time, work with the name and table goes exclusively through the MyDataBaseManager class, sqlite is installed in the current version. So I don't understand where the problem is. Even after renaming the columns in the table, the problem does not disappear. Also, it seems to me that if there was a problem in the structure of the database itself, the error would be given at the time of the build.